# ¿Cómo puedo añadir un padding a un icono que agregue en un botton en android?

Tags: android-studio

He agregado un icono del lado izquierdo de botton de la siguiente manera

```
Drawable drawable = this.getDrawable(refDrawable.intValue());
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, theme.iconsColor.toColor());
DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
button.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
```

¿Como puedo lograr que la imagen se desplace a la derecha solo un poco?

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer `button.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);`?

Comment: Si solo me desplaza el texto a la derecha